# Error submitting form using JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a small web app using JQuery Mobile and Multi Page architecture.

I have a form as my second page. When I click the submit button, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBpww.png) on my console. I need this web app to work on my phone but I'm testing it on my PC browser to see for possible errors.

I'm using localStorage to save the form data in an array in the phone's memory.

Why am I getting this error? I tried with "get" but it just refreshes and takes me back to my home page.

below is my form code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="entry_page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" onclick="clearFields()" data-icon="refresh">Clear</a>
            <h3 id="chickenNameHeader"></h3>
            <a href="#" onclick="showLogs()" data-icon="action" >Show Logs</a>
        </div>

        <div class="form-container">
            <form action="" method="post">

                <label for="ID_input">ID:</label>
                <input id="ID_input" type="number" placeholder="xxxx">

                <label for="weight_input">Weight (g):</label>
                <input id="weight_input" type="number" step="any" min="0" max="10000" placeholder="0. &rarr; 10000">

                <label for="eggs_input">Eggs laid:</label>
                <input id="eggs_input" type="number" min="0" max="4" placeholder="0 &rarr; 4">

                <label for="grain_input">Grain eaten (g):</label>
                <input id="grain_input" type="number" step="any" min="0" max="1000" placeholder="0. &rarr; 1000">

                <label for="category_input">Category:</label>
                <select id="category_input" required="true">
                    <option value="empty" selected></option>
                    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
                    <option value="average">Average</option>
                    <option value="good">Good</option>
                </select>

                <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" name="button">Save log entry</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
            <a id="6" href="#"  onclick="traverse(this)" data-icon="arrow-r" data-ajax="false" >Next</a>
            <a id="7" href="#" onclick="traverse(this)" data-icon="arrow-l" data-ajax="false" >Previous</a>
            <a id="5" onclick="getID(this)" href="#" data-icon="home" >Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is my submit button handler in JS:

```
//Initialise entry page for the first time and handle form submission validation
$(document).delegate("#entry_page","pageinit",function()
{

  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
  }

  changeHeaderName("#chickenNameHeader");

  $("#submitBtn").click(function(event)
  {
    var id = $.trim($("#ID_input").val());
    var weight = $.trim($("#weight_input").val());
    var eggs = $.trim($("#eggs_input").val());
    var grain = $.trim($("#grain_input").val());
    var category = $("#category_input").val();
    var error_free = 1;

    if(id == "")
    {
      alert("Please enter a 4 digit ID");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(weight == "")
    {
      alert("Please enter the amount of weight");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(eggs == "")
    {
      alert("Please enter the amount of eggs laid");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(grain == "")
    {
      alert("Please enter the amount of grain eaten");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(category == "empty")
    {
      alert("Please select a category");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(Number(id) < 1000 || Number(id) > 9999)
    {
      alert("ID must be 4 digits");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(Number(weight) < 0 || Number(weight) > 10000)
    {
      alert("Weight must be between 0. and 10000");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(Number(grain) < 0 || Number(grain) > 1000)
    {
      alert("Grains eaten must be between 0. and 1000");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(latitude == "" || longitude == "")
    {
      alert("Location not given. Please allow location access and refresh the application");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(dateTime == "")
    {
      alert("Date & Time not acquired");
      error_free = 0;
    }

    if(!Boolean(error_free))
    {
      alert("Error saving log. Please fix problems and try again.");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
      var item = {
        id:id,
        dateTime:dateTime,
        latitude:latitude,
        longitude:longitude,
        weight:weight,
        eggs:eggs,
        grain:grain,
        category:category };

        switch (chickenNumber) {
          case 0:
          foghorn_items.push(item);
          localStorage.foghorn_items = JSON.stringify(foghorn_items);
          break;
          case 1:
          little_items.push(item);
          localStorage.little_items = JSON.stringify(little_items);
          break;
          case 2:
          tweety_items.push(item);
          localStorage.tweety_items = JSON.stringify(tweety_items);
          break;
          case 3:
          hawk_items.push(item);
          localStorage.hawk_items = JSON.stringify(hawk_items);
          break;
          case 4:
          bertha_items.push(item);
          localStorage.bertha_items = JSON.stringify(bertha_items);
          break;
        }

        alert("Log saved");
      }
    });
  });
```

**EDIT:** I'm using Nginx as my web server if that helps.

Comment: can you write your js code to understand it better what you getID() function do

Comment: Yes but why? What do I do to fix?

Comment: @bajran getID() is simply to get the ID of some links I have in my first page. Shall I post my submit button js?

Comment: yes you need to post that,  405 error indicates that [ Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource ]

Comment: @bajran Posted the submit button JS code. Basically when I click the submit button, it will validate on my form fields and if it succeeds then it'll save the form data in an array and in the memory of the device.

Comment: @bajran Also, the handler executes and I get all the validation responses. But when it succeeds, I get the "Log saved" alert and then that error comes up

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva, did you check whether your data is storing in local storage

Comment: @In my third page, I have a listview where the data is supposed to be displayed. Nothing comes up on the listview

Comment: and from where you are getting this chickenNumber

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva, please check in local storage in your browser, whether the data is stored or not ?

Comment: @bajran chickenNumber is a global variable in my JS. and I only get this in my console memory tab https://ibb.co/SNL8hm8

Comment: @bajran i'm also using Nginx as my web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting "error_page 405 =200 $uri;" in the Nginx.conf config file made the error go away, but yet to see if my data is getting stored in the memory.